# Enclojure REPL can't find dependent clj file on Load

Tags: clojure, enclojure

I have a problem with the Enclojure REPL and using clojure modules from it. The Load/Change REPL to file/ns works fine with an isolated clojure file, but breaks with a file which has references to another clojure file which I try to use from my project.

Here are the exact steps:

- Create a new project.
- Create a clojure module foobar.clj (namespace com.acme.foobar)
- Define a function which returns a value in foobar.clj:

  (ns com.acme.foobar
    (:use com.acme.othermodule))

  (defn myfunc1 []
    "a")
- Open a Netbeans IDE REPL
- From foobar.clj's context menu select:

  - Change REPL to file/ns
  - Load
- From REPL call the (myfunc1) function. This works just fine:

  com.acme.foobar=> (myfunc1)
  "a"

The problems start when when I try to refer to other files from foobar. Here's what I do:

- Create a new clojure module othermodule.clj

  (ns com.acme.othermodule)

  (defn fromothermodule []
    "b")
- Now try to call this from foobar.clj:

  (defn myfunc2 []
    (fromothermodule))
- From othermodule.clj's context menu I select:

  - Change REPL to file/ns
  - Load

To make the REPL realize that there is new module it should be able to run.

- I do same things things to foobar.clj which now refers to othermodule.clj, but I get:

CompilerException java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate com/acme/othermodule__init.class or com/acme/othermodule.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:50)
com.acme.foobar=>

This error message comes from both "Change REPL to file/ns" and "Load"

What am I missing? Should I do some other tricks to make this happen? Even the desperate measure of Run->Clean and Build the main project doesn't help (that would of course make the REPL business pretty painful anyway).

I am using NetBeans 6.7.1 and enclojure-plugin-2009-11-3.nbm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the right solution from [Eric Thorsen](http://github.com/EricThorsen/enclojure) in the google group:

There are three ways to create the REPL from window-menu. Don't use any of those, instead right
click on the Project and "Start Project REPL". Now the paths are set up accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation is to move from NetBeans/Enclojure to IDEA/La Clojure. JetBrains recently created an open source version of their IDE, and the Clojure plugin works fine in it. Since discovering this, I ditched NetBeans and Enclojure. I find La Clojure a pleasure to work in, but of course your mileage may vary.

Back from when I did this in NetBeans, I seem to remember Enclojure source code resides in a subdirectory called "lib". I think I solved a similar problem by fiddling with directory prefixes on the name of the file to load. Probably something like "../lib/YourName". I managed this by trial and error, so I can't relate the exact rules and syntax.

Two things that might help:

- You can run something like **(println (System/getProperty "java.user.dir"))** to find out where Clojure thinks it's executing from.
- You could start, as I did, with using an absolute path until you find your way to the correct directory name. Something like **"/home/carl/NetbeansProjects/MyProject/lib/myfile.clj"** .

Comment: Thanks! IDEA didn't even cross my mind even though I installed it on my work machine after it was open sourced to check it out. I'll definitely try it.

I'll try your NetBeans tricks also, although the usability suffers considerably if I can't use the "context-menu-over-file-load" option.

Comment: This is embarrassing: It turns out IDEA is the one with the "lib" directory. Heh, I'm glad you got the right answer anyway.